# Merge Date Time in Django ORM

Tags: django

I was trying to combine date and time. For that i was using `datetime.combine`. But it is giving `AttributeError module 'datetime' has no attribute 'combine'`

```
TimesheetEntry.objects.filter(
    timesheet_users = user_id
    ).order_by(
        '-id'
    ).annotate(
        timesheet_clock_in=datetime.combine('timesheet_clock_in_date', 'timesheet_clock_in_time') 
    ).annotate(
        timesheet_clock_out=datetime.combine('timesheet_clock_out_date', 'timesheet_clock_out_time')
    ).values_list(
        'timesheet_clock_in',
        'timesheet_clock_out',
        'timesheet_jobs',
        'timesheet_note',
        'timesheet_clock_in_by'
    )
```

I know the error is in `annotate` but i don't how to solve it. Query works without `annotate`

Comment: can you me your models ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55141480/8283848), use [**`F()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) expressionas

```
from django.db.models import F
from datetime import datetime

TimesheetEntry.objects.filter(
    timesheet_users=user_id
).order_by(
    '-id'
).annotate(
    timesheet_clock_in=datetime.combine(F('timesheet_clock_in_date'), F('timesheet_clock_in_time'))
).annotate(
    timesheet_clock_out=datetime.combine(F('timesheet_clock_out_date'), F('timesheet_clock_out_time'))
).values_list(
    'timesheet_clock_in',
    'timesheet_clock_out',
    'timesheet_jobs',
    'timesheet_note',
    'timesheet_clock_in_by'
)
```

Comment: That's solving the **next** problem yes. The confusing `from datetime import datetime` was the original problem

Comment: @RicharddeWit Yeah. I forgot that. Thanx for the correction

Comment: @JPG It is giving error - `combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not F`

Answer (score 3):

Did you import `datetime` correctly?

```
import datetime
# The datetime module
```

or

```
from datetime import datetime
# The datetime class in the datetime module
```

In the first case you should call `datetime.datetime.combine` (with 2x `datetime`). In the second case you can call `datetime.combine` directly.

Comment: Yea you are right. But know it is giving `TypeError` - `combine() argument 1 must be datetime.date, not str`

Comment: @HuzaifSayyed - that's because you're passing the keys (as strings) into the combine method. It doesn't know you're referencing to the current object.

Comment: @RicharddeWit So what is the solution to this ?

Answer (score 3):

`date.combine()` does not work because it raises **argument 1 must be datetime.date, not F**

#### Here is how we approached this issue:

```
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Cast, Concat

TimesheetEntry.objects.filter(
    timesheet_users=user_id
).order_by(
    '-id'
).annotate(
    timesheet_clock_in=Cast(
        Concat('timesheet_clock_in_date', Value(" "), 'timesheet_clock_in_time', output_field=DateTimeField()),
        output_field=DateTimeField()
    )
    timesheet_clock_out=Cast(
        Concat('timesheet_clock_out_date', Value(" "), 'timesheet_clock_out_time', output_field=DateTimeField()),
        output_field=DateTimeField()
    )
).values_list(
    'timesheet_clock_in',
    'timesheet_clock_out',
    'timesheet_jobs',
    'timesheet_note',
    'timesheet_clock_in_by'
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the database instead of in the ORM:

```
TimesheetEntry.objects.filter(
    timesheet_users = user_id
    ).order_by(
        '-id'
    ).annotate(
        timesheet_clock_in=ExpressionWrapper(F("timesheet_clock_in_date") + F("timesheet_clock_in_time"), output_field=DateTimeField())
    ).annotate(
        timesheet_clock_out=ExpressionWrapper(F("timesheet_clock_out_date") + F("timesheet_clock_out_time"), output_field=DateTimeField())
    ).values_list(
        'timesheet_clock_in',
        'timesheet_clock_out',
        'timesheet_jobs',
        'timesheet_note',
        'timesheet_clock_in_by'
    )
```

`+` is the Postgres operator for date + time → timestamp so make sure you're using the correct operator for your database.

Also as a note to anyone doing this: Be careful of timezone issues when combining date and time into timestamps.